# Apple store - itunes connect - one build per device type

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to pusblish two different builds of the same app in itunes connect with one for ipads only and one for iphones only ?

What is the best approach when we have one build per device type ? Can it all be pusblished with the same app id ?

If not, if each build has to have its own app id (ex: ipad.myapp and iphone.myapp), how can we keep the same application name for both apps ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be publish with two different bundle id , you can have name like for iphone MyApp & for ipad MyApp -HD  because you can't have same name of both the apps

Answer (score 0):

An iOS application is uniquely identified by 3 parameters. App name, Bundle ID and SKU number, So these 3 parameters should be unique for each application. Here is the Link [iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1) and screen shot

[image]